# Correct way to perform correlation

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below works. I want to replace the literal value "2" in the inner most query with the column name `P0.TLKP_Parent`. When I do this I get a Syntax error:

*Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'P0.TLKP_Parent_PK' in 'where clause'*

```
SELECT p0.*,x.nm
From t_child P0
,
(
    SELECT p1.nm
    FROM   mydb.tlkp_parent P1 
    where  p1.lang_cd="FR"
    AND 
    p1.CORE_VAL= 
    (
        select CORE_VAL 
        FROM   mydb.tlkp_parent P2 WHERE 
        (p2.PK =2) '<== want the '2' to be replaced with P0.TLKP_Parent
    )
) as x
where P0.TLKP_Parent_PK=2
```

How to fix this?
Is there a better way to write this query?

Thanks.
Note: The DDL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t_child;

CREATE TABLE t_child (
  Seq_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  SomeData varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  TLKP_Parent_PK int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Seq_id),
  KEY fk_t_Child_TLKP_Parent_idx (TLKP_Parent_PK)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tlkp_parent;

CREATE TABLE tlkp_parent (
  PK int(11) NOT NULL,
  Core_Val int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Lang_Cd char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  nm varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PK)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO tlkp_parent
(PK, Core_Val, Lang_Cd, nm) VALUES
(1,100,'EN', 'A in English'),
(2,101,'EN', 'B in English'),
(3,102,'EN', 'C in English'),
(4,100,'FR', 'A in French'),
(5,101,'FR', 'B in French'),
(6,102,'FR', 'C in French');

INSERT INTO `t_child`
( Seq_id, `SomeData`, `TLKP_Parent_PK`) VALUES 
(1, 'some data for Bed',2),
(2, 'some data for Couch',2);
```

Comment: There's no data in the child table !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry, I have edited the question to add some data. Thanks.

Comment: You insert 3 values into 2 columns. How does that work?

Comment: @Strawberry, good catch! Short attention span is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see the difference between your query and this:

```
SELECT c.*
     , y.nm 
  FROM t_child c 
  JOIN tlkp_parent x 
    ON x.pk = c.tlkp_parent_pk 
  JOIN tlkp_parent y 
    ON y.core_val = x.core_val 
 WHERE y.lang_cd = 'FR';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide a concise and easy to read and understand solution. Very elegant indeed!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the table `P0` is not recognized in the `SELECT`, since it is not part of the `inner join`, try this:

```
SELECT p0.*, (SELECT p1.nm
    FROM   mydb.tlkp_parent P1 
    where  p1.lang_cd="FR"
    AND 
    p1.CORE_VAL= 
    (
        select CORE_VAL 
        FROM   mydb.tlkp_parent P2 WHERE 
        (p2.PK =P0.TLKP_Parent_PK)
    )) as nm
    FROM t_child P0
where P0.TLKP_Parent_PK=2
```

Comment: @NoChance Excellent and clever as may be, there may yet have been further scope for improvement.

Comment: @Strawberry, Any ideas would be great indeed. Do you suggest I ask for optimization in new question?

Comment: Apologies for changing the preferred solution, as the new solution looks simpler and probably more readable to me. I still appreciate your answer as it was timely and correct.